# Grafana don't build docker image

Tags: docker, go, build, grafana

i have a problem to build the docker image for grafana.
i'm trying to build the image with `make build-docker-full-ubuntu` but when
go is building there is an error and the procedure exit with an error:

```
go: downloading github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0
generate go files
/go/bin/wire-v0.5.0 gen -tags "oss" ./pkg/server ./pkg/cmd/grafana-cli/runner
wire: github.com/grafana/grafana/pkg/server: wrote /src/grafana/pkg/server/wire_gen.go
wire: github.com/grafana/grafana/pkg/cmd/grafana-cli/runner: wrote /src/grafana/pkg/cmd/grafana-cli/runner/wire_gen.go
build go files
go run build.go   build
Version: 9.0.7, Linux Version: 9.0.7, Package Iteration: 1660317595
building binaries build
building grafana-server ./pkg/cmd/grafana-server
rm -r ./bin/linux-amd64/grafana-server
rm -r ./bin/linux-amd64/grafana-server.md5
go build -ldflags -w -X main.version=9.0.7 -X main.commit=unknown-dev -X main.buildstamp=1660317595 -X main.buildBranch=main -o ./bin/linux-amd64/grafana-server ./pkg/cmd/grafana-server
embed.go:9:20: pattern cue: no matching files found
exit status 1
exit status 1
make: *** [Makefile:92: build-go] Error 1
The command '/bin/sh -c make build-go' returned a non-zero code: 2
make: *** [Makefile:157: build-docker-full-ubuntu] Errore 2
```

outer the build go is builded correctly but in the image builder fail.

Anyone can help me?

i'm using ubuntu 20.04 e the grafana version is 9.0.7

Thanks in advice

Comment: resolved! miss a COPY cue cue/ in docker file

Answer (score 0):

this is delayed but this might help someone. just elaborating on the resolved comment.
Need to copy the cue folder from the source to the docker
add this line in DockerFile

```
- COPY cue cue
```